# Setup up website and beta site using git

Tags: git, web, webserver

I have a website that I am setting up that I want to use git for version control. My idea is to create a beta subdomain where I can test the site and then 'push' it to the main site in the public_html folder. Everything needs to be on the server to access the database. I tried to actually clone the main site into the beta folder but I receive the following error when trying to push to the main site.

```
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository denied
```

I tried to use a bare repo but that is no good for a website as it does not contain a working tree.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the "git post-receive hook".

On server, you have to use two repositories:

- the bare repository (where you will upload the code by "git push")
- a clone of this bare repository. This clone will host your website

On the bare repository, you configure the post-receive-hook: when the repository is updated, you can automatically perform an update of the clone repository to update your website.

Comment: Thanks your answer pointed me in the right direction, this site helped a lot: http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto